# How do I assign values read in from a .txt file?

Tags: java, text, input, output

I'm working on a program to read in a Wikipedia page view statistics file from a .txt file, so far I have a load method that reads in this file as follows:

```
public void loadPVSF(String x) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(x);   //obtains bytes from an input file
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(f);  //reads primitive java types
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {

            tempArray = temp.split("\n");   //adds each line to an array tempArray

            for (String st : tempArray) //puts each element of tempArray through String st
            {    
                MainArray = st.split(" ");   //adds each string after a " " to MainArray

                for (String str : MainArray) {

                    if(linecounter<5){
                        linecounter++;

                        System.out.println(linecounter + ": " + str);
```

Running this, this is a sample of the following command line output:

```
1: commons.m 
2: Category:Gracie_Gold 
3: 1 
4: 7406
1: commons.m
2: Category:Grad_Maribor
3: 1
4: 7324
1: commons.m
2: Category:Grade_II*_listed_houses_in_Cheshire
3: 1
4: 7781
```

Basically each set of four lines is:

```
1 - Language/Project
2 - Article Title
3 - Number of Page views
4 - Size of the Page (bytes)
```

I need to know how I will go about assigning each one of these read-in lines correctly.
Essentially what I need in the end is a hash table that will store a list of the article titles and their corresponding number of views so that I can determine which one has the largest number of views.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sample of the input .txt file:

nl Andreas_(apostel) 7 103145
nl Andreas_Baader 4 46158
nl Andreas_Bjelland 2 28288
nl Andreas_Burnier 2 11545
nl Andreas_Charles_van_Braam_Houckgeest 1 10373
nl Andreas_Eschbach 1 365
nl Andreas_Grassl 1 365

Comment: Could you post a few sample lines of the INPUT .txt file?

Comment: You'd create a class to represent each record, create an instance of that class for each line, put the value in it, then do whatever it is you want to do with it. What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave,
Where I am stuck is coding the next step. I want to assign each one of the lines 1-4 their correct object. Each line 1 would be a string denoting the language, each line 2 would be a string denoting the Article Title, etc. What I need to end up with is a hash table which contains each article title (2) and it's relative number of views (3) so I can determine after thousands of entires which article has the highest number of views.

I'll post a sample of the input above.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple class like

```
class Page {

String languageOrProject ;
String articleTitle;
int views;
int size ; 

}
```

then you can sort with a Comparator. Or if you need only maximum page views, add it in a `TreeMap` with key as Views and value as pageTitle. At the end you will be able to get least reading page by `map.firstKey()` and max reading page by `map.lastKey()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is kind of the direction I was thinking in going, the only part that has halted me is the stage I am at is the command line output you see above, what I don't know how to do is to assign each one of the lines 1-4 into the corressponding objects. How do I tell the program that each line 1 is the article title, and each line 3 is the page views? I understand what you mean by using a TreeMap, but I don't know specifically how to code this.